# Creating domain name to ec2 instance with masking

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a created a EC2 instance and hosted my application in the amazon cloud and wanted to set the domain name to my EC2 instance (which URL is to long) and I want the domain name to be present in the address bar instead of rediercting to amazons ec2 url in the address bar. I purchased domian from GoDaddy and tried using the GoDaddy forward and masking , as my amazon ec2 instance is https and GoDaddy URL is http , the masking is not happening.
May I know how to achive this?

Comment: Don't use masking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Route 53 to host a DNS entry for your EC2 host.

1. Create a public Hosted Zone: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html
2. Update your registrar (GoDaddy in this case) with 4 DNS servers that appear as NS record in your newly created Hosted Zone: https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-us-12317
3. Attach an elastic IP to your EC2 instance so it has a static IP address: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html
4. Create a new record of type "A" and domain name you desire in your public Hosted Zone.

After a short propagation delay (about a minute) you'll be able to resolve your domain to the IP address of your EC2 instance. You can use a service like this one to watch how your name resolves everywhere: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/t.co. Or https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/t.co (in both cases I used "t.co" as an example domain to resolve, you should provide your name). When DNS updates have propagated everywhere both services should return the elastic IP address of your EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the step by step detailed answer , will it support masking as well?

Comment: I assume you'r referring to [domain masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking) which isn't really a function of DNS but of an application running on a host. A similar effect can be achieved with AWS S3 static website hosting: http://www.holovaty.com/writing/aws-domain-redirection/, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html.